# Refreshed spring cloud server overrides not refreshed for clients

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-boot-actuator, spring-cloud-config

### Goal:

Call actuators refresh endpoint to reload an override specified in spring cloud config server

### Background:

Spring cloud config server provides a way to push out default configuration to all clients through the overrides property (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_property_overrides)
`spring.cloud.config.server.overrides.foo=bar`

Spring actuator provides a `/refresh` endpoint to reload configuration properties while the application is running.

### Problem:

When a new override is pushed into spring cloud config server and the refresh point refreshes that property, the override value is not updated.

Therefore, an update like `spring.cloud.config.server.overrides.foo=baz` shows baz under actuators `/env` endpoint, but the clients still see `foo=bar`.

### Question:

Is this just a missing feature of spring cloud config server?